# source for enterprise disks

Tags: storage, sas, scsi

whats your source for scsi/sas disks - to replace breakage or expand existing systems?  the usual suspects (newegg, pricewatch, ZZF) seem to have limited selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend [Provantage](http://www.provantage.com) among the others listed.

Answer (score 5):

I buy my HP disks from HP, my NetApp disks from NetApp, my EMC disks from...etcetera etcetera - that way I know they're fully supported and I won't be left 'holding the baby' if things start going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely to find @sysadmin1138's [response](https://serverfault.com/questions/185513/source-for-enterprise-disks/185516#185516) to be the common consensus.  I have had decent success with [CDW](http://www.cdw.com/).  However, their price points are not very low without volume.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm buying my servers with support contracts, I replace breakage with OEM parts as part of the contract. The few times we've gone 3rd party have not been for storage.

Comment: id prefer that as well.  in one case service has expired, and in the other id like to compare with MFR pricing.

Answer (score 0):

As with most others, I buy the matching brand-name disks for our brand-name servers.

But there are some marginal cases where we buy 3rd party disks, for example:

- an old server that is out of warranty but we're keeping it around for some reason
- the few white-box servers we've built ourselves
- desktops running simulations (these are essentially in-house built servers)

For these we buy the Western Digital RE series disks that we've found to be very reliable.

Comment: He's asking for a source for tier 1 storage.  SAS, Ultra160/320, SCSI in general.. high end stuff.